# unable to change width of html column

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I have tried some combinations but width of td is not getting changed.
Can someone please guide.I tried changing width to various values.
It is just a part of HTML code.

**Question:** I want to increase the width of first column of every row and reduce the size of textbox.

Total numbers of amortization and total income columns are too small and the testboxes are long than needed.

Fiddler -https://jsfiddle.net/o50d5qjk/

**Portion of HTML**

```
 <div id="bladdiv<%=divcount%>" style="display: none; height: 750px; width: 1020px; overflow-y: auto">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:100px"></td>
            <td>
              <table id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
                <tr>
                  <div class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest rate %</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Amortization per year</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest per year</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
            <td style="width:150px"></td>
            <td>
              <table id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
                <tr>
                  <div class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest rate %</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Amortization per year</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest per year</td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:400px" valign="top">
        <table id="Table_OwnersTogether" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="1020">


          <tr>
            <th style="width: 400px" valign='top'>Income Details</th>


            <th style="width:400px">2018
              <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2019
              <!-- Kalkylränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2020
              <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2021
              <!-- Kalkylränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2022
              <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2023
              <!-- Kalkylränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2024
              <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2025
              <!-- Kalkylränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2026
              <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
            </th>
            <th width="13px">2027
              <!-- Kalkylränta-->
            </th>


          </tr>
          <!-- Inkomst före skatt -->
          <tr>
            <td style="width:250px" valign='top'>Val</td>
            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_MONTHLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>


          </tr>
          <!-- Skatt -->
          <tr>
            <td style="width:250px" valign='top'>val2</td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width:13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_YEARLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_MONTHLY_INCOME_TAX_HH_1  %>'>
            </td>


          </tr>
          <!-- Skattefria inkomster -->

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what is your issue. Can you please provide code snippet or fiddle?

Comment: What `td` are you talking about? You just have multiple headers on one row.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to change width of first column of each row.

Comment: I have added the fiddler and also updated the question.My first column is too conjusted and text comes in multiple lines.Also,the size of textbox is more than i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> table td width </title>
  <style>
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="master-table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:200px" > Session </th>
            <th style="width:100px;" > Module  </th>
            <th style="width:150px;"> Mode of delivery </th>
            <th style="width:300px;"> Duration </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-reactid=".2.1.0.2.0">
        <tr data-reactid=".2.1.0.2.0.0:$0">
            <td> Session 1</td>
            <td> CWTC Pre-Session Webinar 1</td>
            <td> WebEx</td>
            <td> 20 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Session 2 </td>
            <td> CWTC Pre-Session Webinar 2 </td>
            <td> WebEx </td>
            <td> 1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Session 3 </td>
            <td> 1-Day Workshop </td>
            <td> In-Person </td>
            <td> 8 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Session 4 </td>
            <td> Post Workshop Reinforcement </td>
            <td> Self-Paced </td>
            <td> Ongoing </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```